# wmemchr и natvis

Tags: c++, visual-studio, отладка, visual-studio-2019

Есть простой код:

```cpp
class CTest {
public:
    const wchar_t * attr;
    CTest(const wchar_t * attr) {
        this->attr = attr;
    }
};

int main() {
    CTest test(L"_color=red");
    const wchar_t * foundLen = wmemchr(test.attr, '=', wcslen(test.attr));
    std::cout << foundLen;
}
```

Замечательно работает и выводит `=red`.

Теперь к этому классу пишу визуализатор:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010">
  <Type Name="CTest">
    <Expand>
      <CustomListItems>
        <Variable Name="len" InitialValue="wcslen(attr)"/>
        <Variable Name="value" InitialValue="wmemchr(attr, '=', len)"/>
        <Variable Name="value2" InitialValue="wmemchr(attr, '=', len * 2)"/>
        <Item Name="Value">value</Item>
        <Item Name="Value2">value2</Item>
      </CustomListItems>
    </Expand>
  </Type>
</AutoVisualizer>
```

И вижу такую картину:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я правильно понимаю, что в парсере `natvis` баг и он воспринимает последний параметр `wmemchr` как максимальную длину в **байтах** и делит ее пополам?

---

Версия студии Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 (Version 16.8.3)

Comment: похоже на то, можете отправлять им баг репорт

Comment: @user7860670 нет возможности проверить в 2020?

Comment: в 2019 (Version 16.8.4) - воспроизводится, а что такое 2020 - не знаю...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это, действительно, баг. Я оформил [баг-репорт](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/wmemchr-malfunction-in-natvis/1322621) и его взяли в разработку как подтвержденный